# Duplicating Child Window problem

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, childwindow

In my application I have a Submit button that does this:

```
private void Submit_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string variable = variable_textBox.Text;
    if (variable.Length >= 1 && variable.Length <= 6)
    {
        //get some data from db
    }
    else
    {
        ChildWindow msg = new Msg("Some string");
        msg.Show();
    }
}
```

Here is my problem:

When I write a string so that the program goes to the else clause, a childWindow will appear (that is OK); but if I do this again, 2 childWindows will appear. For each click on Submit button, I get num of clicks childWindows.

Can someone tell me why? I use the same ChildWindow in other places, and I have no problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `Submit_button_Click` method is being attached multiple times to the click event (for each click).

Make sure this is not the case by putting a `breakpoint` in there and see if it is hit multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

> I use the same ChildWindow in other
>   places, and I have no problems...

Do you mean with then: When you use childwindows on different places you dont have this problem?
If so, I can only assume when clicking OK you dont just click the top window but also the bottom window.

You can add a behaviour that removes the Submit_button_Click event from the first childwindow.

But why show a message in a childwindow? You can use `MessageBox.Show("Some string")` for that.

Comment: But why show a message in a childwindow? Because someone want this :P

Comment: Noted!
If you're still experiencing this problem, let us know so we can try help further

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
    {
        foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
                return OpenForm;
        }
        return null;
    }


private void Submit_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string variable = variable_textBox.Text;
    if (variable.Length >= 1 && variable.Length <= 6)
    {
        //get some data from db
    }
    else
    {
        ChildWindow frm = null;
            if ((frm = (ChildWindow)IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(ChildWindow))) == null)
            {
                frm = new ChildWindow();
                frm.Show();
            }
            else
            { }
    }
}
```